# Calculating characteristic impedance of a matching line

Tags: transmission-line, impedance-matching, characteristic-impedance, matching

[image]Attached is a question asking for the characteristic impedance of a matching line. A matching line of 0.25\$\lambda\$ has at its beginning an impedance equal to:
$$Z_{in}=\sqrt{Z_{c}Z_{L}}$$
if I am not mistaken.
Hence, in order to find the characteristic impedance one must first determine \$Z_{in}\$. I figured I could normalize \$R_{g}\$ wrt \$Z_{0}\$, which yields \$1\$, and then, using a SC, find \$Z_{in}\$ by moving towards the load a distance of 0.2\$\lambda\$. Is that correct? I'd appreciate your feedback.

Comment: What you're describing is usually called a quarter-wave transformer. It is a matching line, not a matched line.

Comment: Isn't your formula for \$ Z_{in} \$ wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're required to find the \$ Zc \$ that will match the load to the line with a quarter wave transformer.

Because \$ R_g = Z_0 = 100 \Omega \$, the impedance at the junction, looking towards the generator, is \$ 100 \Omega \$. So you need the same impedance (actually, its complex conjugate) looking towards the load from the junction, i.e. \$ Z_{in} = 100 \Omega \$.

The load is fixed at \$ R_L = 400 \Omega \$, thus:

$$
Z_s = \sqrt{Z_{in} R_L} = 200 \Omega
$$

Now that we have matched the load through the quarter wave transformer, we can calculate the voltage phasor \$ V_L \$, because all the power available from the generator will be delivered to the load.

The maximum power available from the generator is:

$$
P_{avail} = \frac {1}{8} \frac {|V_g|^2} {R_g}
$$

And the power delivered to the load can be expressed as:

$$
P_L = \frac {1}{2} \frac {|V_L|^2} {R_L}
$$

Thus:

$$
\frac {1}{8} \frac {|V_g|^2} {R_g} = \frac {1}{2} \frac {|V_L|^2} {R_L}
$$

So we obtain the magnitude of the phasor:

$$
|V_L| = \frac {1}{2} |V_g| \sqrt {\frac{R_L}{R_g}} = 100V
$$

The phase is related to the electrical lengths of the transmission line sections:

$$
\arg(V_L) = - \beta_1 l_1 - \beta_s l_s = - \frac {2\pi}{\lambda_1} 1.2 \lambda_1 - \frac {2\pi}{\lambda_s} 0.25 \lambda_s = - 2.9 \pi
$$

And finally:

$$
V_L = 100V \cdot e^{- j 2.9 \pi}
$$

Comment: Thank you very much! As for the second part of the problem, namely the phasor at the load \$V_{L}\$, if the impedance at the junction between the two transmission lines is \$100\ohm\$, could I simply use it to find the impedance at the junction right before the first transmission line and then use voltage divider to determine the voltage at that junction? Then, upon finding that voltage, I could move it back \$1.2\lambda\$ towards the load to find the phasor voltage. Is this the right approach?

Comment: Need I also to find the reflection coefficient?

Comment: You have to calculate \$V_L\$ taking advantage of the fact that you have matched everything in your system. See my edit.

Comment: Mind that I also need the phase for complete phasor format. Here's a different approach: the impedance at the juncture between the two transmission lines is \$100 \ohm\$. Using voltage divider the voltage at the beginning of the first transmission line should be \$50V\$. Moreover, the very same voltage also equals \$V^+_{1}(1+ \gamma_{1})\$, where \$V^+_{1}\$ is the propagating voltage at the beginning of the first transmission line and \$\gamma_{1}\$ the reflection coefficient at the beginning of the first transmission line.

Comment: This reflection coefficient equals \$0\$. Hence, \$V^+_{1}=50V\$. Thus, the phasor voltage at the end of the first transmission line (junction between two lines) should be equal to \$V^+_{1}(1+ \gamma_{1})exp^{-j2 \pi / \lambda_{1}* 1.2 \lambda_{1}}\$. The voltage at the load should therefore be: \$50 exp^{-j2.4 \pi}exp^{-j0.5 \pi}(1+ \gamma_{L})\$ where \$ \gamma_{L}=1/3\$. Is that correct?

Comment: You're overthinking this. Keep it simple by sticking to the fact that all available power is delivered to the load. Your phase calculation looks OK to me.

Comment: So should it simply be 100exp(-j2.9*pi)?

Comment: I think so, unless I'm wrong. What's troubling you?

Comment: Why does the more tedious approach not yield a similar result?

Comment: Also, are you certain the magnitude ought to be 100?

Comment: And, shouldn't the phase be multiplied by the complex number j?

Comment: Oh, yes. Sorry about that.

Comment: But what about the more elaborate approach, why doesn't it yield the same answer?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/57609/discussion-between-enric-blanco-and-peripatein).